# How to start a postgresql instance from bash script within a docker container

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, docker-compose

I want a Dockerfile (with official PSQL image) to call a script that eventually starts up the PSQL server. The reason for this, instead of calling `postgres` in the `CMD` of the Dockerfile, is that I need to copy some files from a shared volume first.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:latest

WORKDIR /db

COPY ./start.sh /db/start.sh

EXPOSE 5432

CMD ["bash", "start.sh"]
```

`start.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

cp ..$SHARED_VOL_SAVE_PATH/$FILE_NAME ./ && \
su - postgres && \
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS postgres" && \
psql postgres < $FILE_NAME
```

This set up yields the following error

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
db-1     |  Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

---

Sidenote, as I understand it, `su - postgres` is a little outdated but is an alternative to installing `sudo`. And I tried running `postgres` as `root` but that resulted in,

```
db-1     | "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
db-1     | The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
db-1     | possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
db-1     | more information on how to properly start the server.
```

Unsure of best way to handle this but just providing context here.

---

Here is the `compose.yml` file. The db service and the service that writes the file I need to copy are in separate containers.

```
services:
  fetch:
    build: fetch/.
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - backuprestore:/data_dumps/
  db:
    build: db/.
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - backuprestore:/data_dumps/
    depends_on:
      fetch:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  backuprestore:
```

Comment: Which bit is supposed to be starting up PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sidestepping your question, but I think what you are trying to achieve could be done with initialization scripts, see "Initialization scripts" under https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres. You mgiht be able to mount the sql dumps volume directly to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/.

Comment: @RichardHuxton, the second line of the sh script. But I see that the user _and_ the command are `postgres`. `su - postgres  postgres` yields ` -bash: postgres: No such file or directory` though.

Comment: @TeemuRisikko, thanks. I will look at sticking start up scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` next.

Answer (score 0):

As @teemu-risikko pointed out, it was better to mount the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` dir as a volume and write my `*.sql` files to it for either service to use. The PSQL image looks in that dir and runs any scripts on initialization so long as there isn't already a pre-existing DB. This was much better than my approach.

`Dockerfile`

```
# OIDs aren't supported in latest psql but they're in dump
FROM postgres:10

WORKDIR /db

# Not needed. SQL files for init are already
# in dir. start.sh runs a query to check that
# restore happend correctly.
COPY ./start.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 5432

CMD ["postgres"]
```

`start.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

psql -c "SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_restored_table LIMIT 10;"
```